# Change progressBar color in ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I just want to change the color of the progressBar in a ProgressDialog (style horizontal). So I created this custom shape xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <size android:height="3dip"/>              
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#33FF33"
                android:endColor="#008000"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

And here is the result (under Android 4.4)

[image: Custom progress bar]

It looks like Android 2.x. I want it to be as thinner as Android 4.x is, like this:

[image: default progressbar]

I also tried to set `<size android:height="3dip">` but didn't work.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height in your layout xml file where you have specified progressbar

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"   <!-- THIS WILL SET HEIGHT OF PROGRESS BAR -->
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar" />
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
<shape>
    <corners android:radius="3dip" />
    <size android:height="8dp" />
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
            android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#ff747674"
            android:angle="270"
    />
</shape>
</item>

 </layer-list>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've created it on code and I don't know how to set these attribute programmatically. http://pastebin.com/mCCM54MU

Comment: When I call my progress.show(); it shows as picture above, with a strong line instead of thin one

Comment: Set height of progressbar as android:layout_height="8dp" in your layout xml file

Comment: But as I said, I created my progressDialog programmatically, I do not have defined in any xml resource :(

Comment: Oh got it! Sorry!! In your case you can add <size android:height="8dp"/> this line in the drawable file in shape tag. see edited ans

Answer (score 0):

you can use LayoutParams

```
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.this, null,          android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 10);

        progressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        LinearLayout test = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        test.addView(progressBar);
        setContentView(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use item's tag,
top,bottom to change item's height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:top="5dp"
          android:bottom="5dp">
        <color android:color="@color/red"/>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
          android:top="5dp"
          android:bottom="5dp">
        <clip>
            <color android:color="@color/blue"/>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```